# Preventing the use of Credit Card Gift Cards?

Tags: validation, credit-card

I've got an eCommerce system that accepts Visa, Mastercard, Discover, and Amex for recurring billing. An issue we've run into is that in some instances, people have used pre-loaded gift cards rather than real credit cards, and once the balance runs out the recurring payment fails.

I'm trying to find a way to determine if a card number is a gift card or not. Is there any sort of unique characteristics to these credit card gift cards? Is there any way to tell from part of the Issuer Identification Number? We've already got validation to check the IIN and determine the card type, but I would expect the issuers use some set of digits to identify the prepaid cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have a possibility to detect it from the card data you get from the user. The number is just an ID to identify the card in the issuer's database, and that's the location where such details are defined.

Comment: Also, credit card companies are unlikely to allow a differentiation between temporary and permanent credit cards. They don't want temporary credit cards to be banned from sites *because* they're temporary.